# Determining Path of Nikon d5300 camera connected via USB

Tags: python, directory, camera, windows-10, mediadevices

I am trying to set up a python script that will listen to a Nikon d5300 camera that is connected to a laptop via USB. The idea is: as pictures are being snapped on the camera by another automated rig, I want the python script to be able to identify the new images and move them off the camera and organize them into a folder on the laptop.

So far I have written the entire python script and tested it by listening to local folders and it is working exactly as I wanted it to.

Now I just have to change the directory that the script is listening on, and change it to the path to the camera. The problem I am facing is that the Camera shows up as a device under the path "This PC"; I know that this is not an actual path and cannot be passed to python.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can obtain the path to the camera or how I can map the camera as a drive (saw that as a partial solution on the web, but it seems like it requires putting the camera in some sort of Mass Storage Mode)?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks folks!